# Подсчитать количество вхождений слов в предложение

Tags: linux, bash

Есть ли элегантный способ подсчета количества вхождений слов в предложение? Стандартная юниксовская команда, или все это реализуется как-то иначе?

Под текстом подразумевается некий текстовый массив, за слова все, что разделено пробелами.

---

имеется ввиду не количества слов всего, а сколько раз каждое слово встречается в предложении.

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, что именно вы подразумеваете под «предложением» и под «словом». грамматические определения, как вы понимаете, не очень подходят в данном случае.

Comment: В какое предложение ? А если предложений несколько считать в каждом отдельно. Вообще есть команда `wc` считает байты/слова/строки в входном файле

Comment: @Ярослав, постарайтесь, пожалуйста, сосредоточиться и изложить в тексте вопроса, что же именно вам нужно. да, выражение «некий текстовый массив», кстати, тоже требует расшифровки (или переформулировки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настоятельно советую всё-таки завести под рукой нечто вроде книжки "Основы работы в Linux". Всё это относится к базовым вещам работы с консолью. Данный случай - например, [man awk](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=awk&category=1), переменная `NF`:

```
echo "слово1 слово2 слово3" | awk '{ print NF; }'
```

Вывод: `3`.

---

С учётом дополнительных условий (размашисто и подробно):

```
echo "слово1 слово1 слово3" | awk '{ \
  for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { \
    words[$i]++; \
  } \
  for( word in words ) { \
    total++;
  }\
  print total;
}'
```

В общем, ответ тот же: [man awk](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=awk&category=1) + справочник по основам работы в Linux.

Comment: извиняюсь, поправочка, здесь имеется ввиду не количества слов всего, а сколько раз каждое слово встречается в предложении

Comment: См. обновлённый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

попробую угадать, исходя из правок вопроса и комментариев.

вероятно, у вас есть файл, в котором есть строки текста. и вам надо составить список всех слов (это набор символов, разделённых пробелом), отсортировать его и удалить дубликаты, подсчитав, сколько раз они встретились.

сделать это можно, например, так:

```
$ cat исходный-файл | sed 's/ \+/\n/g' | sed '/^$/d' | sort | uniq -c
```

например, для пяти абзацев классического [lorem ipsum](http://ru.lipsum.com/) вывод будет таким (в первой колонке количество повторов слова, само слово — во второй колонке):

```
  5 a
  1 a,
  3 ac
  1 ac,
  2 accumsan
  1 ad
  1 adipiscing
  4 Aenean
  2 aliquam
  1 Aliquam
  2 aliquet
  5 amet
  2 amet,
  3 ante
  1 ante.
  1 aptent
  6 arcu
  1 arcu.
  5 at
  1 at.
  1 auctor
  3 augue
  1 bibendum
  1 blandit
  1 Class
  2 commodo
  1 condimentum
  1 condimentum.
  1 congue.
  3 consectetur
  1 consectetur.
  1 consequat
  1 conubia
  3 convallis
  1 convallis,
  1 Cras
  1 Cum
  1 Curabitur
  3 cursus
  5 dapibus
  3 diam
  1 diam.
  1 dictum
  1 dignissim
  1 dignissim,
  1 dis
  2 dolor
  5 Donec
  1 dui,
  1 dui.
  1 Duis
  2 efficitur
  1 egestas
  1 egestas,
  4 eget
  2 eleifend
  1 elementum
  2 elit
  1 elit.
  3 enim
  2 enim,
  2 enim.
  3 erat
  1 erat,
  1 erat.
  5 est
  1 est.
  6 et
  2 Etiam
  5 eu
  1 eu,
  1 euismod,
  6 ex
  1 facilisis
  7 faucibus
  4 felis
  3 fermentum
  2 finibus
  2 fringilla
  2 fringilla.
  2 Fusce
  1 gravida
  1 hendrerit
  1 hendrerit,
  1 himenaeos.
  3 iaculis
  4 id
  1 id,
  1 imperdiet
  1 imperdiet,
  5 in
  3 In
  1 inceptos
  3 Integer
  2 interdum
  1 interdum,
  1 interdum.
  2 ipsum
  1 ipsum,
  1 ipsum.
  1 justo
  2 lacinia
  1 lacinia,
  1 lacus
  1 lacus.
  1 laoreet
  3 laoreet,
  1 laoreet.
  2 lectus
  1 lectus.
  3 leo
  1 leo,
  1 leo.
  2 libero
  1 libero.
  6 ligula
  1 ligula.
  1 litora
  2 lobortis
  2 lorem
  1 Lorem
  1 luctus
  1 luctus.
  2 Maecenas
  3 magna
  1 magnis
  3 malesuada
  1 malesuada.
  1 mattis,
  1 mattis.
  5 mauris
  1 mi.
  1 molestie
  1 mollis
  1 mollis,
  1 montes,
  1 mus.
  2 Nam
  1 nascetur
  1 natoque
  6 nec
  1 nec,
  3 neque
  1 neque.
  1 nibh
  1 nibh.
  1 nisi
  1 nisl
  2 non
  1 non,
  1 nostra,
  2 nulla
  1 nulla.
  3 Nullam
  1 nunc
  1 Nunc
  4 odio
  1 odio,
  1 orci
  1 orci.
  1 ornare.
  1 parturient
  1 pellentesque
  1 pellentesque.
  2 Pellentesque
  1 penatibus
  2 per
  1 Phasellus
  2 porta
  1 porttitor
  2 porttitor.
  1 posuere
  2 Praesent
  2 pretium
  2 pretium.
  3 Proin
  1 pulvinar,
  1 purus
  3 quam
  1 quam,
  1 quam.
  3 quis
  3 Quisque
  2 rhoncus
  1 ridiculus
  4 risus
  3 risus.
  1 rutrum,
  1 rutrum.
  1 sagittis
  1 sagittis,
  1 sapien
  1 sapien,
  2 scelerisque
  4 sed
  1 sed,
  3 Sed
  2 sem
  7 sit
  1 sociis
  1 sociosqu
  1 sodales,
  4 sollicitudin
  1 sollicitudin.
  2 suscipit
  2 Suspendisse
  1 taciti
  1 tellus
  2 tempor
  1 tempor.
  3 tempus
  1 tempus.
  3 tincidunt
  2 tincidunt,
  1 tincidunt.
  1 torquent
  1 tortor,
  1 tristique.
  3 turpis
  1 turpis,
  1 ullamcorper
  1 ultrices
  1 ultrices.
  1 ultricies
  1 ultricies.
  2 urna
  7 ut
  2 Ut
  1 varius
  1 varius.
  2 vehicula
  1 vehicula.
  5 vel
  1 venenatis
  2 Vestibulum
  5 vitae
  1 vitae,
  1 Vivamus
  1 viverra
  1 viverra.
  1 volutpat.
  4 vulputate
```